# How to get all the details I ticked in a table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, pdfmake

I'm using PDFMake to generate a bunch of details of each person I ticked in my table.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: ticked]

In every ticked I make I should generate their details in separate coupon bond **(pageBreak)** in a PDF using PDFMake along with their QR Code. I successfully prints that in my console:

[image: output]

Here's my code for that:

```
var docDefinition;
  for (var vin = 0; vin < this.selected.length; vin++) {
    var nestedArr = new Array(this.selected);

    var s = nestedArr[0][vin].LAST_M + "\n" + nestedArr[0][vin].MEMB_N;
    console.log(s);

    docDefinition = {
      pageSize: "A6",
      pageMargins: [0, 0, 0, 0],
      content: { text: s }
    };
  }

  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).print();
},
```

But when it comes to generation of PDF with their details, it only generates the last ticked person and not all the persons I ticked. As you can see in the image below:

[image: pdfmake]

I guess the problem is on **docDefinition** because it creates an instance every time I generate a PDF and only gets the last person I ticked.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `docDefinition` is rewritten every time in for loop, so it only takes last value. You can change to:

```
var docDefinition;
var text = []
for (var vin = 0; vin < this.selected.length; vin++) {
  var nestedArr = new Array(this.selected);

  var s = nestedArr[0][vin].LAST_M + "\n" + nestedArr[0][vin].MEMB_N;
  text.push(s)
}
docDefinition = {
  pageSize: "A6",
  pageMargins: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  content: { text: text.join("\n") }
};
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).print();
```

Comment: is it possible to add a pageBreak to each data?

Answer (score 0):

This trick worked for me. 
Grabbed the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318654/pdfmake-make-pdf-from-dynamical-content-an-array)  also from GitHub

```
 var docDefinition;
  var text = [];
  for (var vin = 0; vin < this.selected.length; vin++) {
    var nestedArr = new Array(this.selected);

    var s = nestedArr[0][vin].LAST_M + "\n" + nestedArr[0][vin].MEMB_N;
    text.push(s);
  }

  var docDefinition = {
    content: text.map(function(item) {
      return { text: item, pageBreak: "after" };
    })
  };
  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).print();
```